# Replication pull job on subscriber stopped running when removing article from publication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

Version: SQL Server 2014 (Web edition)
Replication: Transactional

Came across an odd issue whereby the replication pull job on 10 of our 45 subscribers stopped running when removing article from corresponding publication.

This was completed through the GUI and didn't see any errors in distributor's SQL log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your drop the article from publication, but you can assign again
just execute this

```
exec sp_addsubscription @publication='your_pub',@article='all',@subscriber='your_server'
```